# Python Machine Learning - Multi Class Testing Script

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I'm quite new to machine learning, and I am currently building / running a script to test a dataset against multiple classifiers to find out which one offers the best fit / highest accuracy and then use that classifier to make my predictions.

So far when ever I run the script I am getting very high scores, around 98% - 99%. I just want to make sure that these high scores aren't due an error on my part. I ***think*** I have covered all bases, I'm using cross validation, checking it against a confusion matrix etc. But as I say, I am new to this.

My code is below;

```
import csv
import pandas
import numpy as np
import sklearn.ensemble as ske
import operator
from sklearn import model_selection, tree, linear_model, svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB


# Load dataset
url = 'four_During_1000.csv'
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url)
#dataset.set_index('Name', inplace = True)
dataset.drop('Name', axis = 1, inplace=True)

# Split-out validation dataset
X = dataset.drop(['Legitimate'], axis=1).values
Y = dataset['Legitimate'].values
seed = 7
scoring = 'accuracy'


print('Researching important feature based on %i total features\n' % X.shape[1])

# Feature selection using Trees Classifier
fsel = ske.ExtraTreesClassifier().fit(X, Y)
mdl = SelectFromModel(fsel, prefit=True)
X_new = mdl.transform(X)
nb_features = X_new.shape[1]

features = []

print('%i features identified as important:' % nb_features)

indices = np.argsort(fsel.feature_importances_)[::-1][:nb_features]
for f in range(nb_features):
    print("%d. feature %s (%f)" % (f + 1, dataset.columns[2+indices[f]],
                                   fsel.feature_importances_[indices[f]]))

# XXX : take care of the feature order
for f in sorted(np.argsort(fsel.feature_importances_)[::-1][:nb_features]):
    features.append(dataset.columns[2+f])
print("\n")

X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(
    X_new, Y ,test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

# create dict for models
models = {
    "LR" : linear_model.LogisticRegression(),
    "KNN": KNeighborsClassifier(),
    "DecisionTree": tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    "RandomForest": ske.RandomForestClassifier(),
    "GradientBoosting": ske.GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    "AdaBoost": ske.AdaBoostClassifier(),
    "GNB": GaussianNB(),
    "SVC": svm.SVC(),
    "SVM": svm.OneClassSVM(),
    }

# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
score = {}
for name in models:
        clf = models[name]        
        kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
        cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(clf, X_train,
                                                     Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
        results.append(cv_results)
        msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
        score[name] = cv_results.mean()
        print(msg)
print("\n")

winner = max(score, key=score.get)
print('\nWinner algorithm is %s with a %f %% success' % (winner, score[winner]*100))
print("\n")

# Make predictions on validation dataset
clf = models[winner]
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
#score1 = clf.score(X_validation, Y_validation)
predictions = clf.predict(X_validation)
print(accuracy_score(Y_validation, predictions))
print(classification_report(Y_validation, predictions))
mt = confusion_matrix(Y_validation, predictions)
print("False positive rate : %f %%" % ((mt[0][1] / float(sum(mt[0])))*100))
print('False negative rate : %f %%' % ( (mt[1][0] / float(sum(mt[1]))*100)))
```

My question is, anyone can see what I might be doing wrong, or what I could do better? As a side note, my data samples are fairly small at the moment (1000), however I am working to increase the size of my datasets at the moment.

**EDIT:**

The following link contains the data held in my .csv file (included above)

https://codeshare.io/5ZQkRe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune, this is an exact copy and complete copy of my code, with the exception of the classifiers I am using (as I didn't feel they would have much bearing on the subject of cross validation etc), however I will edit and add those in now.

Comment: The main problem I see with the example would be `'four_During_1000.csv': file not found`, or some similar message.

Comment: @Prune, that is the .csv file I am using that holds my dataset... These can simply be swapped out with a sklearn library, such as the iris dataset or pama dataset. But those are very small sets, however are I believe loaded into sklearn.

Comment: Ah!  Okay, if SKLearn people can reproduce the problem with *any* data set, I'm fine with the code.  I can't handle this with my current facilities and faculties, but wanted to make sure that your question is ready to use for those who can.

Comment: @Prune, no worries, I have added in a link to a codeshare site which has the contents of my .csv file in it, so all people need to do is copy, paste and save to have a 100% replication of my data... Seems the most accurate way to test, as mentioned I think an sklearn dataset will just be too small.